# Label correctly associated with radio button only the first time the jQuery UI dialog is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a custom helper for managing my radio buttons. It allows me to click on the label to select the corresponding radio button. It works but I found a situation where it didn't work anymore.

**Here is the scenario**: the first time the jQuery UI dialog is loaded, I'm able to click on a label to select the corresponding radio button. I must say that my radio buttons are loaded into a form in a jQuery dialog.

**The problem** occurred if I close then reopen the jQuery dialog, then my labels are no more associated with the radio buttons (but everything works pretty well except that point).

[image]

Here is the code of my helper:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object labelText)
    {
        object currentValue = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;
        string nameX = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).DisplayName;
        string uniqueId = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).DisplayName + "_" + value;

        TagBuilder htmlRadio = new TagBuilder("input");
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("id", uniqueId);
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("name", nameX);
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("value", (string)value);

        if (currentValue != null && value.ToString() == currentValue.ToString()) htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

        TagBuilder htmlLabel = new TagBuilder("label");
        htmlLabel.MergeAttribute("for", uniqueId);
        htmlLabel.SetInnerText((string)labelText);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlRadio.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + htmlLabel.ToString());
    }
```

This code produces html code like this:

```
<input name="ADR" id="ADR_Yes" type="radio" value="Yes"/>
<label for="ADR_Yes">Oui</label>
```

As you can see label is correctly associated with input.

Do someone have any idea why it works only the first time the jQuery UI dialod is loaded?

I'm a bit lost.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom helper to associate a label with it's input. `LabelFor` and `RadioButtonFor` should do this automatically. Also, can you reproduce this without ASP.NET MVC? (e.g. in jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It doesn't work with ASP.NET MVC. The LabelFor helper does not produce html code with a unique ID. Example: if you have a radio button for 'Yes' and another one for 'No' related to the 'ADR' model attribute, you'll have the same ID for both so it doesn't not work. This problem is known.

Comment: Are you loading the dialog box content through ajax?

Comment: Yes I do. Do you want that I show you the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

Whenever I need to close the jquery dialog, I must destroy it completely from the DOM.

I replaced this line:

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

With the following:

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Maybe this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Rebind your radio handler in ajax success. WHen you invoke it first time it will only be working on existing elements at that time

Comment: How can I do that? Binding the fact that when I click on a 'label for' the radio button associated must be selected. I don't have any code behind this. Thanks.

Comment: if there's no code behind it then would have to see problem live, issue doesn't make sense unless script is changing something which a dialog won't just by closing

Comment: I hope someone who already encountered this problem can help me.

Comment: post a link to live version, can see a lot in a browser console